# filter sql query with case columns in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a query like this :

```
SELECT
  tbl.EmpID,
  CASE
    WHEN emp.status = 'terminated' THEN CONVERT(bit, 1)
    ELSE CONVERT(bit, 0)
  END AS 'Status',
  CASE
    WHEN tbl.LeaveTypeId = 'a' THEN CONVERT(bit, 1)
    ELSE CONVERT(bit, 0)
  END AS 'Absent',
  CASE
    WHEN (tbl.outime IS NULL) AND
      (tbl.LeaveTypeId <> 'a' and tbl.LeaveTypeId Is  null) THEN CONVERT(bit, 1)
    ELSE CONVERT(bit, 0)
  END AS 'InOut',
  emp.EmpFullName,
  tbl.P_Date,
  cmp.cmplogo,
  emp.nation_id,
  emp.dept_id,
  emp.desig_id AS 'designation_id',
  emp.tradecd,
  emp.comp_id,
  emp.section_id,
  emp.location_id,
  emp.emplcatgry
FROM tblattendance tbl
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEEs emp
  ON emp.empid = tbl.empid
INNER JOIN Company cmp
  ON cmp.comp_id = emp.comp_id 
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10), tbl.p_date, 112) BETWEEN '20160901' AND '20160902'
```

my out put coming like this

```
empid status absent inout
121     1     1      1
122     0      0      0
```

but only i want to get result with status,absent,inout greater than 0,so how i can write where condition.

Comment: not sure what was intended, but this: `(tbl.LeaveTypeId <> 'a' and tbl.LeaveTypeId Is  null)` doesn't make sense, as if it's NULL, it can never be compared with chars.  Should it be OR instead of AND?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT S.* FROM ( SELECT   tbl.EmpID,   CASE
     WHEN emp.status = 'terminated' THEN CONVERT(bit, 1)
     ELSE CONVERT(bit, 0)   END AS 'Status',   CASE
     WHEN tbl.LeaveTypeId = 'a' THEN CONVERT(bit, 1)
     ELSE CONVERT(bit, 0)   END AS 'Absent',   CASE
     WHEN (tbl.outime IS NULL) AND
       (tbl.LeaveTypeId <> 'a' and tbl.LeaveTypeId Is  null) THEN CONVERT(bit, 1)
     ELSE CONVERT(bit, 0)   END AS 'InOut',   emp.EmpFullName,   tbl.P_Date,   cmp.cmplogo,   emp.nation_id,   emp.dept_id,  
 emp.desig_id AS 'designation_id',   emp.tradecd,   emp.comp_id,  
 emp.section_id,   emp.location_id,   emp.emplcatgry FROM tblattendance
 tbl INNER JOIN EMPLOYEEs emp   ON emp.empid = tbl.empid INNER JOIN
 Company cmp   ON cmp.comp_id = emp.comp_id  WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10),
 tbl.p_date, 112) BETWEEN '20160901' AND '20160902' )  S WHERE
 S.Status>0  OR S.Absent>0 OR S.InOut>0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a condition like this:

```
WHERE . . . AND
      (emp.status = 'terminated' or tbl.LeaveTypeId = 'a' or
       (tbl.outime IS NULL AND (tbl.LeaveTypeId <> 'a' and tbl.LeaveTypeId Is  null)
      )
```

Alternatively, you could use a subquery or CTE to refer to the columns in the `SELECT`.

EDIT:

The CTE looks like

```
with cte as (<your query here>)
select cte.*
from cte
where status = 1 or absent = 1 or inout = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `CROSS APPLY` with a `VALUES` statement, this allows you to reuse the values in subsequent joins, `WHERE` clause, etc.

e.g.

```
SELECT
  tbl.EmpID,
  v.Status,
  v.Absent,
  v.InOut,
  emp.EmpFullName,
  tbl.P_Date,
  cmp.cmplogo,
  emp.nation_id,
  emp.dept_id,
  emp.desig_id AS 'designation_id',
  emp.tradecd,
  emp.comp_id,
  emp.section_id,
  emp.location_id,
  emp.emplcatgry
FROM tblattendance tbl
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEEs emp
  ON emp.empid = tbl.empid
INNER JOIN Company cmp
  ON cmp.comp_id = emp.comp_id 
CROSS APPLY (
  VALUES (
  CASE
    WHEN emp.status = 'terminated' THEN CONVERT(bit, 1)
    ELSE CONVERT(bit, 0)
  END,
  CASE
    WHEN tbl.LeaveTypeId = 'a' THEN CONVERT(bit, 1)
    ELSE CONVERT(bit, 0)
  END,
  CASE
    WHEN (tbl.outime IS NULL) AND
      (tbl.LeaveTypeId <> 'a' and tbl.LeaveTypeId Is  null) THEN CONVERT(bit, 1)
    ELSE CONVERT(bit, 0)
  END
  )
) v (Status, Absent, InOut)
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10), tbl.p_date, 112) BETWEEN '20160901' AND '20160902'
  AND (v.Status | v.Absent | v.InOut) = 1;
```

Once you have defined `v`, you can use it like any other table in the query. I personally find these simpler to use than a CTE and more readable than a subquery. You can define expressions that depend on tables above the `CROSS APPLY` and then use the values in any joins below, `WHERE` clause, `GROUP BY` etc.

Also, note the use of `|`, the bitwise or operator, to return 1 if any of the `BIT` values = 1.